# Change content in div OUTSIDE of accordion via JQuery AJAX on accordion entry (which needs to be a <a href>)

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-ui-accordion

I want to have a JQuery UI accordion as menu and when clicked on an entry in there to update content in the main content area via DIV next to the menu.

What do I need to add to the  so that it calls JQuery AJAX so it updates the main div? I really would prefer to keep  and not use a form button for doing this. I've looked on here and also googled for a solution but the answers I've found are either about using AJAX to generate the accordion in the first place or to update the accordion menu itself - none of which helped me solve my problem.

Please help me, I just don't know anymore what to do! Thanks!

Code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#nav").accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true
  });
});
```

and:

```
<div id="nav">
  <h3><a href="">Home</a></h3>
  <h3>Select below:</h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="page1.php">This link shows the content of page 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main">
This is the main content area:
Here is the default content shown when the page loads
and needs to be replaced when one of the menu entries
are selected but without loading the whole page, thus
via AJAX and DIV update; also the content is provided
via a PHP file that reads it out from a DB.
</div>
```

---

Update 1 - the full working code as of now:

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="../jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#nav").accordion({
active: false,
collapsible: true
});
});

jQuery(function($){
$("#nav").on("click", "a", function(event){
$('#main').load(this.href);
event.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>

<div id="nav">
<h3><a href="">Home</a></h3>
<h3>Select below:</h3>
<div>
<ul>
  <li><a href="loadContent.php?page=1">This link shows the content of page 1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="main">
This is the main content area:
Here is the default content shown when the page loads
and needs to be replaced when one of the menu entries
are selected but without loading the whole page, thus
via AJAX and DIV update; also the content is provided
via a PHP file that reads it out from a DB.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and loadContent.php:

```
<?php
$request = $_REQUEST['page'];
if (!$request) {
$outputStr = "This is the default content...";
}
else {
$outputStr = "New content: 'page' value = ".$request;
}
exit($outputStr);
?>
```

Comment: Where is your ajax code?

Comment: @Ghommey: Hi - I have an implementation using AJAX but:
1. The <a href> is replaced with a form button and that works but I need the <a href> to be in place instead of a button;
2. The AJAX code is not the one from JQuery, which I'd prefer to use if possible. If it would help for me to post the non-JQuery AJAX code I can, but it shouldn't really be necessary - if you think otherwise just post another comment here and I will. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might just use [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#nav").on("click", "a", function(event){
       $('#main').load(this.href);
       event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Any idea how that would load content via AJAX (which is from the server side "loadContent.php" provided by pulling out the content from a DB) into <div id="main">? Or don't I need AJAX for that?

Comment: Right now it uses the page1.php because of the href. But using  .load("loadContent.php") would also work.

Comment: You got two `h3` headlines try to remove one

Comment: @MikeyJ StackOverflow is not a discussion board but a Q&A system. The idea is to gather as many generic questions as possible. So you might turn your question about hiding the link in a new one. Or search for it maybe it has been already asked before :)